# How to change tomcat home page to my application home page

Tags: java, tomcat

I run tomcat server and put `http://localhost:8080/` on browser. but it is not shown my application home page. and just show **tomcat home page**.

Please, where and **how to change to appear my homepage**

[image]

> [INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/
>
> [INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at D:\Tutorial2\zayarmyat2\first-web-application\target\tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the [context path](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html) when you deploy the application.  [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-root-application)'s a quick tutorial on how to deploy to the context root.